# What happens to the content in my app after i upgrade/update the version in iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am storing a lot of images, books, audios etc of my app in

`Documents Directory/Library/caches` folder.

What happens to all the content if the user updates the version of the app from the app store or from iTunes. Will all of them get erased or will they be untouched during the app updating process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be untouched during the upgrade process. I would like to note however that the `Caches` folder is meant to be used for data that is just cached rather than data you expect to always be available. The OS reserves the right to get rid of anything in the caches folder. If you're asking this question then I assume you want the data to be persistent so you should be aware that since iOS 5, Apple [specifically state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1) that data in the caches directory can be deleted at any time (apart from whilst your app is running).

Answer (score 0):

They are supposed to remain untouched. There are a lot of existing examples for this behavior - try checking any photo sharing application or games that download levels in-game.